# How to show less than a specific percentage in an Excel pivot table?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007, pivot-table

I have a pivot table made in Excel and I already have all the % collected data there.

Now, what I need to do is show only the critical ones which are less than 85%, as I don't need anything above that being shown.

Is there a way I can show less than 85% or any other amount in the future?

Comment: I've modified grammar and re-worded pieces here and there to make it more readable.  Also, for future reference, we don't add signatures with "Thank you" or the like at the end of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another column to your raw data. Set formula to [assuming the % is in column A]:

```
=A1<85%
```

Add this column to your pivot table as a filter. Filter for where your new column = TRUE.

**Edit for new info**

Per your comments below, the %'s are not actually calculated "within" the pivot table, they are next to the pivot table on the same tab. So, simply add an "if" statement to that formula, like so:

```
= if(('Total Paid'+'Total Contr. Adj.')/('Total Billed Amount'-'Other Adj.'-'Write-Off')<85%,('Total Paid'+'Total Contr. Adj.')/('Total Billed Amount'-'Other Adj.'-'Write-Off'),"")
```

This will check to see if your formula is <85%. If it is, the formula will appear there.

Comment: i should have mentioned that the %collected tab in the pivot table is actually calculated within the pivot table itself. it isnt in any raw data outside.

Comment: @MoeKhan Could you elaborate? How are the values calculated? Is there an Excel 2013 feature to allow the automatic calculation of %'s within Pivot Tables? Im not familiar with that in Excel 2010 (I could be wrong).

Comment: = ('Total Paid'+'Total Contr. Adj.')/('Total Billed Amount'-'Other Adj.'-'Write-Off')

Comment: So that was used in the pivot table field to calculate the percentage. Now i tried to do this in the raw data tab and the numbers come out even larger than 100% sometimes which is incorrect obviously.

Comment: @MoeKhan See my edit to my answer and see whether that gives you what you need.

Comment: Hmm its coming out very weird in the raw data tab. It comes out either 100% or 0% which is obviously wrong.

Comment: @MoeKhan Edit your question to include a complete description of your pivot table tab, your raw data tab, some example data, and the formulas used to calculate the %.

Comment: i actually found a much simpler way to do it but still thanks!